# Trouble Resolving spaCy Dependency in Maven Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, spacy

I'm encountering difficulties resolving the spaCy dependency in my Maven project. I've followed several steps to include it in my project's pom.xml, but I'm still facing issues. Here's a summary of the problem and the steps I've taken:

Problem:
When I try to include the spaCy dependency in my Maven project, I receive the following error message during the build process:

`Could not find artifact com.explosion:spacy:pom:3.1.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)`

Actions Taken:

Added spaCy Dependency: In my pom.xml file, I included the spaCy dependency as follows:

```
`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.explosion</groupId>
    <artifactId>spacy</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
 </dependency>`
```

Checked Central Repository: I confirmed that spaCy version 3.1.3 exists in the central Maven repository.

Tried Other Repositories: I attempted to resolve the issue by adding alternative repositories to my pom.xml as follows:

```
`<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>explosion</id>
        <url>https://maven.anaconda.org/conda-forge/simple</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>`
```

Cleaned and Rebuilt: I ran mvn clean install to clean the project and rebuild it, but the issue persists.

Checked Network Connection: I ensured that my network connection is stable and that I can access the repositories.

Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to resolve the spaCy dependency issue. What steps can I take to successfully include spaCy in my Maven project?

Comment: How did you confirm that there is such dependency in Maven repository?

Comment: I have browsed but haven't found the Maven dependency related to that so alternatively I used the

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version> <!-- Check for the latest version -->
        </dependency>

Comment: Okay, because you stated that spacy exists in the maven and I've also have not found it, so that is the reason why I posted a comment